# How to implement reward video ad for each button

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to imolement rewarded video ads in my app
How to implement reward video ad for each button ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understant your question but if you mean to have a different reward according to what button you press you can:

```
private int button_counter = 0:

private void button1 {
   button_counter = 1;
}
private void button2 {
   button_counter = 2;
}


@Override
 public void onReward {
   if(button_counter == 1) {
         Reward1;
         button_counter = 0;
 }
   if(button_counter == 2) {
         Reward2;
         button_counter = 0;
 }
```

If you are having trouble implementing rewarded video you can follow this tutorial: https://youtu.be/9yIDuRPMQm8